# load in background while displaying a ProgressDialog + pause code execution

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I apologize for the wordy title - I wasn't sure how to phrase this exactly. I am trying to (within my onCreate() method):

-Initialize some things

-display a progress dialog while I load some data from my backend

-clear the progress dialog, and then continue on with the code

I understand the the typical progress dialog solution is an asynctask, which I have tried using (see below). However, this does not lock up code execution like I want to. The code that comes after the lwpd.execute() relies on the loading having already happened. Am I overcomplicating this? What is the correct way to do what I want to?

For reference, my Asynctask implementation:

```
public class LoadWithProgressDialog extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    private ProgressDialog pd; //the progress dialog
    private String title; //the title of the progress dialog
    private String  message; //the body of the progress dialog
    private Runnable task; //contains the code we want to run in the background
    private Context c;


    public LoadWithProgressDialog(Context context,String t, String m,Runnable r){
        super();
        c = context;
        task = r;
        title = t;
        message = m;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        pd = ProgressDialog.show(c,title, message, false, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
        task.run();
        return true;
    }
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            pd.dismiss(); 
   }





}
```

and

```
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            //initialize variables


            LoadWithProgressDialog lwpd = new LoadWithProgressDialog(this,"Loading","Loading Truck Data", new Runnable() {
                public void run(){
                    //code that loads things
                }
            });
            lwpd.execute();

//continue on with my code

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the progress dialog in an async task.

Any code that you want to execute after the data has loaded can be put in the onPostExecute method!

```
public LoadWithProgressDialog(Context context,String t, String m,Runnable r){
    super();
    c = context;
    task = r;
    title = t;
    message = m;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){
    pd = ProgressDialog.show(c,title, message, false, false);
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
    task.run();
    return true;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        pd.dismiss(); 

      // PUT YOUR CODE THAT YOU WANT TO RUN AFTER THE DATA HAS LOADED HERE!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not locking code execution is the point of an AsyncTask. If you want it to block code execution just create a ProgressDialog on the main thread